# Instance has an external IP (static) but cannot view via IP address in browser

Tags: tcp, google-compute-engine, firewall, gcloud

I have a Compute Engine instance running with a static external IP address assigned to it, running

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

Shows me indeed the instance and the appropriate external IP address.

I would have thought that visiting that IP address in the browser would show my application?

I have enabled Firewall Rules to the network:

0.0.0.0/0  tcp:80; tcp:443; tcp:9000; tcp:23

I am asking, because I am trying to point my custom domain name to my app, so I have set my A record with my domain registrar to the external IP.

How can I view my app via my external IP address in the browser, is it possible?

Comment: What you're describing should work. Are there firewall settings on the host VM instance? What operating system are you running on the host instance? Have you restarted the instance since updating the firewall rules (shouldn't be necessary in theory, but I've found it to help in practice)? If you listen on the instance on ports 80/443 without your app running, can you telnet in? The failure could be at one of any points in the network link between the internet and your machine.

Comment: I would have thought so too. 

Yes, there are firewall settings on the host VM instance:

I have not restarted but I will give that a go.

I cannot telnet in - connection failed.

What do you mean by 'if you listen on the instance on ports 80/443 can i telnet in' sorry?

I run telnet 'o 1.2.3.4.5.6.7' (External static IP address of instance) and it just says connection failed.

I should mention this is a free trial, perhaps there is some limitations with it that have not been made clear? I also find it strange that on my VM instance the options 'allow http' and 'allow https' are greyed out.

Comment: ^ the same firewall setting are on my VM instance - in Compute Engine, one actually applies the firewall rules to the 'network', then the instance can optionally inherit those firewall rules.

Comment: By "firewall settings on the host VM instance" I meant an operating-system level firewall--no matter whether Google Compute Engine allows packets in, if the operating system is blocking them you cannot receive them (sub-question: are you listening on the right network interface?). Can you access this host from another Compute Engine VM using the "internal IP"?

Comment: Sorry, I did not answer your earlier question...The instance is running Debian, Debian GNU/Linux, 7.9 (wheezy), amd64 with backports kernel and SSH packages built on 2015-09-29. I will try to access this VM from another VM using the internal ip.

Also, whilst we are here, do you have any experience with 'development' file editor showing updated files that were git via gcloud, but when running preview from the shell the updated files are not shown i nthe preview? It seems like developer console is caching.

Comment: Are you able to SSH to the instance? Assuming you can, have you considered non-GCE problems? for example, your app may be binding to localhost. Try explicitly binding to 0.0.0.0. You may also have iptables setup although that is unlikely unless you did it yourself or are using something nonstandard.

Comment: I have restarted to no avail. I am unable to SSH to the instance. When i do as per: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#standardssh i receive 'port 22 Bad file number'. I will look into your other suggestions. In the meantime. Still scratching my head.

Comment: ...even changing ssh to use port 443 (SSL) does not help. Seems to be pointing to something wrong with GCE.

Comment: Ok - progress - I can now ssh into the instance. I had to change the instance to be 'user managed' not managed by Google. I will reply with any further progress. But yes, I can now SSH in to the instance using its external IP address. However, I still am unable to telnet or view it in the browser.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en_US#firewalls

" If you are experiencing issues receiving traffic on your virtual machine instance even after you have configured your firewall, check that your operating system firewall is configured to permit the traffic."

How do I check the operating system firewall is configured to permit the traffic?

Debian, Debian GNU/Linux, 7.9 (wheezy), amd64 with backports kernel and SSH packages

Comment: Please limit each question to one topic. You said that you had to switch this VM to "user-managed"; is this running an App Engine app? How was this VM created?

Comment: What web server are you running on that VM (apache, nginx, ...?) and how is it configured? As for telnet, are you running telnetd, and have you opened the firewall to port 23? BTW, this seems fully a serverfault question, not a stackoverflow one, as it's all about system and network administration.